# How to prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{3x^2+0.5(x-1)^2y^2}$ doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Initially I thought the limit was 0, but when I checked in Wolfram Alpha's calculator, I got that the limit doesn't exist.

Why is this the case? I couldn't find a trajectory for which the limit doesn't exist, so how am I supposed to find out it doesn't have a limit? Can I prove its non-existence using the epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: take the case where x=y and compute the limit.

Comment: I did that, but I'm left with the following one variable limit: $\frac{(x)^3}{2.5(x)^2 +0.5(x^4) - x^3}$ as x->0. If I substitute the x for 0, I would get an indeterminate form of the 0/0 kind. And when using L'Hopital, I end up with the limit being equal to 0, which doesn't assure me if the limit exists or not.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is wrong, assuming you didn't make a typo when asking it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @user254665

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=0,$ then $f(x,y) = 0.$ Otherwise

$$|f(x,y)| = |y|\frac{x^2}{3x^2 +.5(x-1)^2y^2} \le |y|\frac{x^2}{3x^2} = \frac{|y|}{3}\le |y|.$$

Thus in all cases, $0\le |f(x,y)| \le |y|.$ By the squeeze theorem, the desired limit is $0.$

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Was it something in particular that led you to use the squeeze theorem though? Because I don't think I could've come up with that solution on my own. Maybe it's just lack of practice anyway, I normally try a few trajectories and that allows me to either assert the limit doesn't exist or prove it by epsilonics.

Also, how come Wolfram's calculator (http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=2958433016861a528d6221f5ac88eefd) tells me there's no limit for this funcion?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the $(1-x)^2$ term is essentially $1$ if $x$ is small. So just treat it as $1$ for intuition. Also forget the $3$ and the $.5$ constants at the beginning; they seem like distractions for the unwary. You're left with

$$\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}.$$

Upstairs we have the power $3,$ downstairs we have two terms of power $2$ added together. For small numbers, a power of $3$ is much smaller than a power of $2.$ So my guess was $0$ for the limit. Once you have a guess, it's much easier to proceed.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your reasoning! It really helps me out to come up with similar thought processes on my own :)

Answer (score 1):

we have
$|f(x,y)|<\frac{|y|}{3}$

so , $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Disregard that comment.

Comment: I don't quite get it anyway :/

Comment: Correct conclusion. The absolute value of the denominator, when $x,y$ are not both $0,$ is at least $3x^2. $  So $  |f|\leq |x^2y|/3x^2=|y|/3. $ Although we do have equality when $  y=0\ne x.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**-Put $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$ and see that $Lim_{r→0}f(rcos\theta$,$rsin\theta$) exists and is zero.

Comment: But if that limit using polar coordinates exists, can I assert that the limit exists?

Comment: if it does not depend on $\theta$, then surely yes.

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated but I wouldn't give a down-vote.